# foldRight Efficiency?

Tags: scala

I heard foldLeft is much more efficient in most of operations, but Scala School (from Twitter) gave the following example. Can someone give an analysis of its efficiency and should we achieve the same operation using foldLeft?

```
val numbers = List(1,2,3,4,5,...10)
def ourMap(numbers: List[Int], fn: Int => Int): List[Int] = {
    numbers.foldRight(List[Int]()) { (x: Int, xs: List[Int]) =>
    fn(x) :: xs
  }
}

scala> ourMap(numbers, timesTwo(_))
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you can see from the docs, `List`'s foldRight and foldLeft methods are defined in `LinearSeqOptimized`. So take a look at the source:

```
override /*TraversableLike*/
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
  var acc = z
  var these = this
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    acc = f(acc, these.head)
    these = these.tail
  }
  acc
}

override /*IterableLike*/
def foldRight[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B =
  if (this.isEmpty) z
  else f(head, tail.foldRight(z)(f))
```

So `foldLeft` uses a while-loop and `foldRight` uses a simple-recursive method. In particular it is not tail-recursive. Thus `foldRight` has the overhead of creating new stack frames and has a tendency to overflow the stack if you try it on a long list (try, for example `((1 to 10000).toList :\ 0)(_+_)`. Boom! But it works fine without the `toList`, because `Range`'s `foldRight` works by reversing the folding left).

So why not always use `foldLeft`? For linked lists, a right fold is arguably a more natural function, because linked lists need to be built in reverse order. You can use `foldLeft` for your method above, but you need to `reverse` the output at the end. (Do not try appending to Lists in a left fold, as the complexity is O(n-squared).)

As for which is quicker in practice, `foldRight` or `foldLeft` + `reverse`, I ran a simple test and `foldRight` is faster for Lists by between 10 and 40 %. This must be why List's foldRight is implemented the way it is.

Comment: Can I clarify your answer regarding the last statement? It's not the case that foldRight is generally 10%-40% faster than foldLeft, but when a reverse operation is included then this difference is to be expected. When choosing between a left or a right fold, the possibly-high cost of stack frame needed for a right fold counts against it, but the high cost of a reverse counts against using a foldLeft with a reverse. If foldLeft (without reverse) is an option, it seems to be the preferable choice overall.

Comment: Note, I believe `List`'s `foldRight` just does left fold + reverse in recent versions of Scala, probably to avoid stack overflows

Answer (score -2):

foldRight reverses the list and applies foldLeft.