# List foldRight Always Using foldLeft?

Tags: scala

I just looked at the [List.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala?source=cc)’s implementation of `foldRight()`.

```
  override def reverse: List[A] = {
    var result: List[A] = Nil
    var these = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      result = these.head :: result
      these = these.tail
    }
    result
  }

  override def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B =
    reverse.foldLeft(z)((right, left) => op(left, right))
```

As I understand it, calling `foldRight` on a `List` results in calling `theList.reverse.foldLeft(...)`.

Is `List.foldRight` implemented with `foldLeft` in order to take advantage a single stack frame rather than using multiple stack frames with `foldLeft`?

Comment: Implementation seems to have changed at some point since 2.10! `foldRight` used to be simple recursive and was like 10% - 40% faster than reversing and fold-lefting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004715/foldright-efficiency and 2.10.0 source: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1

Comment: Why would it have changed, Luigi?

Comment: Stack overflow errors. I think Martin had been holding out for aesthetic and maybe performance reasons.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`foldLeft` is tail-recursive, `reverse` isn't recursive at all: this implementation ensures constant memory usage. `foldRight`, when not implemented in terms of `foldLeft`, isn't tail-recursive, which makes it unsafe for large amounts of data.

Note: there might be ways to make `foldRight` tail-recursive, but all those I can think of need to append things at the end of a list, which means traverse it in its entirety. If you're going to do that anyway, better use `foldLeft` and reverse the result, it involves far fewer full iterations on the whole list.

Comment: While the current version is tail-recursive, the costs of reversing the list will stack up... So if you are doing it several times in a row, go with `foldLeft` and reverse the list at the end... Or even better, try a collection best suited for your requirements, such as `Vector`.

Comment: [Fixing previous deleted comment] Just to complement Nicolas Rinaudo answer, `while` loops are fast! Functional + immutable idioms tends to scale better. Imperative + mutable style tends to have better raw performance. So reverse takes linear time but it is actually fast. `foldRight` was enhanced to user reverse + foldRight, previously it was not tail recursive (see v2.0 [List.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/78c4deeb632f850357a0c938f33d0f556756f64c/src/library/scala/List.scala)). Anyway linear time is linear time, so, whenever you can, follow the above advice.

Comment: As an interesting note, Scalaz implements `Foldable#foldLeftM` in terms of `foldRight`.

Comment: `makes it unsafe for large amounts of data.` This applies only to data stored on the stack? As I understand here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593362/outofmemory-exception-when-creating-stream-of-3-digit-products), using tail recursion with Stream's can lead to OutOfMemory exception due to data strictly evaluated on the heap.

Comment: Technically, you shouldn't use a `Stream` as an accumulator in a tail-recursive call - a `Stream` is, in a way, its own accumulator. Aside from that, a non-tail-recursive function is unsafe because each further call to itself results in a new stack frame, which will eventually result in a `StackOverflowError` if you go "deep" enough. A tail-recursive function is optimised to execute itself in a single stack frame (it becomes, in essence, a `while` loop) and will not result in a stack overflow however large the amount of data to process.

Comment: I posted another question based on this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370549/foldleft-v-foldright-does-it-matter