# Implementing `sequence` on a Monad

Tags: scala, monads

Working on another exercise to implement `Monad.sequence()` from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), my answer differs from the official/known-to-be correct answer:

> def sequence[A](lma: List[F[A]]): F[List[A]]

[Official](https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/7b962343a977d59e63d315b9622ac060203f643b/answerkey/monads/3.answer.scala):

```
def sequence[A](lma: List[F[A]]): F[List[A]] =
  lma.foldRight(unit(List[A]()))((ma, mla) => map2(ma, mla)(_ :: _))
```

Mine:

`def sequence[A](lma: List[F[A]]): F[List[A]] = F(lma.flatten)`

Example where **F** is `Option`:

```
scala> val x: List[Option[Int]] = List( Some(1), None)
x: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), None)

scala> Some(x.flatten)
res1: Some[List[Int]] = Some(List(1))
```

Is my answer (or the spirit of it) legitimate here?

I get the following compile-time exception, but I'm sure if it's related to my lack of understanding of type constructors.

> Monad.scala:15: error: not found: value F
>                  F(lma.flatten)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `Option(1)`, what's actually happening is that you're calling the `apply` method on the `Option` companion object. This is only very indirectly related to the `Option` type—specifically, there's no way in general to get the `Something` companion object (which is a value) if you only have a type variable referring to the `Something` type. In fact there's no guarantee that the companion object even exists, and even if it does exist, its `apply` method might return something that's entirely not an instance of the `Something` type. The fact that `X.apply(...)` does return an `X` in the case of `List` and `Option` and case classes is entirely a matter of convention.

The other part of the issue here is the call to `List.flatten`. If you look at the "Full Signature" for `flatten` in [the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List), you'll see that it has an implicit argument:

```
def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: (A) => GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]
```

This means that you can only use it on a `List[A]` if `A` can be implicitly converted into a `GenTraversableOnce` of some kind. This isn't the case in general for any old monad.

I'd encourage you to prove these things to yourself, though—try your implementation with some of the other monads from the exercises and see where things break down.

Comment: Thanks, Travis. I always learn from your answers. As a side question, why is `foldRight` being used here instead of `foldLeft`?

Comment: Thanks! And I'm not entirely sure about `foldRight` here. In a sense `foldRight` is simpler than `foldLeft`, since you can think about it as just replacing the cons operator with the provided function and the empty list with the provided initial value. And given an appropriately non-strict definition, `foldRight` can be used on infinite lists (or streams), while `foldLeft` can't.

Comment: As a follow-up, how can `foldRight`, but not `foldLeft`, be used on an infinite list/stream if it's implemented in terms of foldLeft? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547976/list-foldright-always-using-foldleft