# OutOfMemory Exception when Creating Stream of 3 Digit Products

Tags: scala, out-of-memory

I wrote a function that produces a Stream[Long] consisting of the products of x-digit numbers.

For example, 2 digit numbers is 1 to 99 (inclusive).

```
  def getXDigitProducts(x: Int): Stream[Long] = {
    val MAX = Math.pow(10, x)
    @tailrec
    def go(outer: Int, inner: Int, acc: Stream[Long]): Stream[Long] = 
     (outer, inner) match {
      case (MAX, _) => acc
      case (_, MAX) => go(outer + 1, 1, acc)
      case (_, _)   => go(outer, inner + 1, Stream[Long](outer * inner) ++ acc)
    }
    go(1, 1, Stream[Long]())
  }
```

Waltkthrough:

```
> Example: getXDigitProducts(2) will produce a stream of:
> 
> 1*1 1*2 1*3    ... 1*98 1*99
> 2*1 2*2 2*3    ... 2*98 2*99
> 99*1 99*2 99*3 ... 99*98 99*99
```

Using x = 2 works, but passing in x = 3 throws an `OutOfMemory` exception on `outer = 668`.

What is the cause of this exception?

When executing `Stream[Long](outer * inner) ++ acc`, is there some intermediate Stream that isn't getting properly garbage collected?

Comment: Not too familiar with the inner workings of Scala but it seems to me that you cannot "garbage collect" the intermediate values until you return from the final (MAX,_)- . Does this get quadratically slower as well? If you have to make copies of the stream on each call that might show itself through a dramatic slowdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floris is absolutely right. Once you call `go`, it will only return once it reaches `case (MAX, _)`. At that point, *everything* has been created and allocated in memory.

I see you tried to ensure tail recursion, but the trick with `Stream` is to *not* have tail recursion. You want to build the *start* of a `Stream`, and append the recursion call to it.

This won't cause stack overflow problems because, instead of recursing, the function will return at that point, and the "recursive" call will only be made once you access that element of the stream -- at a higher level in the stack.

So, get rid of `acc`, and turn this

```
go(outer, inner + 1, Stream[Long](outer * inner) ++ acc)
```

into this

```
(outer * inner) #:: go(outer, inner + 1)
```

or something similar -- you might have to do a little exploring to find out how to ensure you don't evaluate the recursive calls strictly.

Comment: So the reason for not using tail recursion with a Stream is that we don't want the Stream to be entirely evaluated immediately? If we don't use tail recursion, then we won't run into a StackOverflow since the Stream is lazily evaluated?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yes, and, well, it depends. A Stream's tail is lazily evaluated, but you gotta make sure you use methods that will take that tail as a by-name parameter.

Comment: Hmm. I successfully got the answer using your suggested method, Daniel - https://gist.github.com/kman007us/9774414. Thanks. However, I also was able to use my above solution without getting an `OutOfMemory` error as I had before encountered. Why would my function fail previously, but not now?

Comment: @KevinMeredith The only reason I can think of is that now it has enough memory. As far as I can see, your solution _will_ create all of the stream element before returning.