# foldLeft v. foldRight - does it matter?

Tags: scala, haskell

Previously, [Nicolas Rinaudo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370349/nicolas-rinaudo) answered my question on Scala's [List foldRight Always Using foldLeft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547976/list-foldright-always-using-foldleft)

Studying Haskell currently, my understanding is that `foldRight` should be preferred over `foldLeft` in cases where `::` (prepend) can be used over `++` (append).

The reason, as I understand, is performance - the former occurs in `O(1)`, i.e. add an item to the front - constant time. Whereas the latter requires `O(N)`, i.e. go through the whole list and add an item.

In Scala, given that `foldLeft` is implemented in terms of `foldRight`, does the benefit of using `:+` over `++` with `foldRight` even matter since `foldRight` gets reversed, and then `foldLeft'd`?

As an example, consider this simple `fold..` operation for simply returning a list's elements in order.

`foldLeft` folds over each element, adding each item to the list via `:+`.

```
scala> List("foo", "bar").foldLeft(List[String]()) { 
                                                    (acc, elem) => acc :+ elem }
res9: List[String] = List(foo, bar)
```

`foldRight` performs a foldLeft with `::` operator on each item, but then reverses.

```
scala> List("foo", "bar").foldRight(List[String]()) { 
                                                    (elem, acc) => elem :: acc }
res10: List[String] = List(foo, bar)
```

In reality, does it matter in Scala which `foldLeft` or `foldRight` to use given that `foldRight` uses `foldRight`?

Comment: I think you'll find that in the current version of Scala, `foldLeft` is not implemented in terms of `foldRight`, at least for lists: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala

Comment: No, `foldLeft` is not implemented in terms of `foldRight`. It's the other way around for `List`: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/99a82be91cbb85239f70508f6695c6b21fd3558c/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L391-L392

Answer (score 52, accepted):

@Rein Henrichs' answer is indeed irrelevant to Scala, because Scala's implementation of `foldLeft` and `foldRight` is completely different (for starters, Scala has eager evaluation).

`foldLeft` and `foldRight` themselves have actually very little to do wrt the performance of your program. Both are (liberally speaking) O(n*c_f) where c_f is the complexity of one call to the function `f` that is given. `foldRight` is slower by a constant factor because of the additional `reverse`, though.

So the real factor that differentiates one from the other is the complexity of the anonymous function that you give. Sometimes, it is easier to write an efficient function designed to work with `foldLeft`, and sometimes to `foldRight`. In your example, the `foldRight` version is best, because the anonymous function that you give to `foldRight` is O(1). In contrast, the anonymous function that you give to `foldLeft` is O(n) itself (amortized, which is what matters here), because `acc` keeps growing from 0 to n-1, and appending to a list of n elements is O(n).

So it actually *matters* whether you choose `foldLeft` or `foldRight`, but not because of these functions themselves, but because of the anonymous functions given to them. If both are equivalent, choose `foldLeft` by default.

Comment: I assume it also matters in Scala if the function is non-associative?

Comment: Well, yes, obviously. Given the formulation of the question, I assumed this much was clear.

Comment: That seems reasonable since I did the same thing. ;)

Comment: Thanks, @sjrd. Per Nicolas's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370549/foldleft-v-foldright-does-it-matter/24371661#comment37710483_24370549) to my question, I'm not sure if this answer is still correct in 2.12 given that `foldRight` no longer is implemented in terms of `foldLeft`, as I understand from this source code link?

Comment: `foldRight` is still implement in terms of `foldLeft` as of 2.12.0-M3: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/99a82be91cbb85239f70508f6695c6b21fd3558c/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L391-L392

Answer (score 13):

I can provide an answer for Haskell, but I doubt it will be relevant to Scala:

Let's start with the source for both,

```
foldl f z []     = z
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs

foldr f z []     = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

Now, let's look at where the recursive call to foldl or foldr appears on the right hand side. For foldl, it is outermost. For foldr, it is inside the application of f. This has a couple important implications:

1. If `f` is a data constructor, that data constructor will be left-most, outermost with foldr. This means that foldr implements [guarded recursion](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/07/data-and-codata.html), such that the following is possible:

   ```
   > take 5 . foldr (:) [] $ [1..]
   [1,2,3,4]
   ```

   This means that, e.g., foldr can be both a good producer and a good consumer for [short-cut fusion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Short_cut_fusion). (Yes, `foldr (:) []` is an identity morphism for lists.)

   This is not possible with foldl because the constructor will be inside the recursive call to foldl and cannot be pattern matched.
2. Conversely, because the recursive call to foldl is in left-most, outermost position, it will be reduced by lazy evaluation and will not take up space on the pattern-matching stack. Combined with proper strictness annotation (e.g., `foldl'`), this allows functions like `sum` or `length` to run in constant space.

For more on this, see [Lazy Evaluation of Haskell](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/lazy.xhtml).

Comment: I really like this description of the two!

Comment: The **tl;dr**: use `foldr` for lazy and `foldl'` for strict processing.

Answer (score 11):

It does in fact matter whether you use `foldLeft` or `foldRight` in Scala, at least with lists, at least in the default implementation. I believe this answer not to hold true for libraries such as scalaz, though.

If you look at the source code of `foldLeft` and `foldRight` for [LinearSeqOptimized](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala), you'll see that:

- `foldLeft` is implemented with a loop and local mutable variables, and fits in one stack frame.
- `foldRight` is recursive, but not tail recursive, and thus consumes one stack frame per element in the list.

`foldLeft` is thus safe, while `foldRight` might stack overflow for long lists.

*Edit*
To complete my answer, as it only adresses part of your question: it also matters which one you use depending on what you intend to do.

To take your example, what I consider the optimal solution is to use `foldLeft`, prepending results to your accumulator, and `reverse` the result.

This way:

- the whole operation is O(n)
- it will not overflow the stack, regardless of the size of the list

This is essentially what you thought you were doing with `foldRight` when assuming that it was implemented in terms of `foldLeft`.

Should you use `foldRight`, you'll get a slightly faster implementation (well, slightly... twice as fast, really, but still O(n)) at the cost of safety.

One could argue that, if you know your lists are going to be small enough, there is no safety issue and you can use `foldRight`. I feel, but that's only an opinion, that if your lists are small enough that you don't have to worry about your stack, they're small enough that you don't have to worry about the performance hit either.

Answer (score 6):

It depends, consider the following:

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) { (acc, ele) => ele :: acc }
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)

scala> l.foldRight(List.empty[Int]) { (ele, acc) => ele :: acc }
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

As you can see, `foldLeft` traverses the list from `head` to the last element.  `foldRight` on the other hand traverses it from the last element to `head`.

If you use folding for agregation, there should be no difference:

```
scala> l.foldLeft(0) { (acc, ele) => ele + acc }
res2: Int = 6

scala> l.foldRight(0) { (ele, acc) => ele + acc }
res3: Int = 6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> val words = List("Hic", "Est", "Index")
words: List[String] = List(Hic, Est, Index)
```

**Incase of foldLeft:**
 List elements will add to the empty string first and followed

```
words.foldLeft("")(_ + _) == (("" + "Hic") + "Est") + "Index"      //"HicEstIndex"
```

**Incase of foldRight:**
Empty string will add to end of elements

```
words.foldRight("")(_ + _) == "Hic" + ("Est" + ("Index" + ""))     //"HicEstIndex"
```

Both cases will return the same output

```
def foldRight[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Scala expert, but in Haskell, one of the most important differentiating features between `foldl'` (which really should be the default left fold) and `foldr` is that `foldr` will work on infinite data structures, where `foldl'` will hang indefinitely.

In order to understand why this is, I recommend visiting [foldl.com](http://foldl.com/) and [foldr.com](http://foldr.com), expanding the evaluations a couple of times, and reconstructing the call tree. You'll quickly see where `foldr` is appropriate versus `foldl'`.